# ksqlDB server fails to start when connecting to existing kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have an existing kafka broker at <myurl>:9092. That broker is running Apache Kafka version 2.2.0. I would like to use ksqlDB to do some stream processing on data from topics on that kafka broker. Thus, I am using ksqlDB from Confluent Platform version 5.2, according to the compatibility table at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html.

I've set `bootstrap.servers=<myurl>:9092` in `ksql/ksql-server.properties`.

However, when I try to start the ksql-server by running `ksql-server-start etc/ksql/ksql-server.properties`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:53)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition _confluent-ksql-default__command_topic-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.Command`, problem: `java.lang.NullPointerException`
 at [Source: (byte[])"("statement":"CREATE STREAM KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG (logger VARCHAR, level VARCHAR, time BIGINT, message STRUCT<type INT, deserializationError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, recordB64 VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>, `topic` VARCHAR>, recordProcessingError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, record VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>>, productionError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR>>) WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='default_ksql_processing_log', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');","originalProperties":{"ksql.extension.dir":"ext","ksql.streams.ca"[truncated 3011 bytes]; line: 1, column: 3511]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.Command`, problem: `java.lang.NullPointerException`
 at [Source: (byte[])"("statement":"CREATE STREAM KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG (logger VARCHAR, level VARCHAR, time BIGINT, message STRUCT<type INT, deserializationError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, recordB64 VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>, `topic` VARCHAR>, recordProcessingError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR, record VARCHAR, cause ARRAY<VARCHAR>>, productionError STRUCT<errorMessage VARCHAR>>) WITH(KAFKA_TOPIC='default_ksql_processing_log', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');","originalProperties":{"ksql.extension.dir":"ext","ksql.streams.ca"[truncated 3011 bytes]; line: 1, column: 3511]
...
```

If I use a local broker and set `bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092`, ksql-server starts without any problems.

How do I get around this null record/deserialization issue in order to connect a ksqldb server to my existing kafka broker?

Comment: If no one else uses KSQL on that cluster, you could delete `_confluent-ksql-default__command_topic`. Otherwise, change the command topic name in the ksql config

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer, deleting the topic works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @OneCricketeer pointed out, the problem is arising from an existing command topic on the cluster. You can use a fresh command topic by changing the [`ksql.service.id`](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/server-config/config-reference/#ksqlserviceid) in the ksqlDB server properties. See [Configuring ksqlDB server](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/server-config/).